# Color scatter plot in Matlab according to 0 or 1 value

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, scatter

I populate a grid `data=zeros(n,n);` with 0's and 1's (could also be thought of as an adjacency grid, if you'd like). I just want to plot the grid with colors according to whether the value at that point is 0 or 1. For example,

```
scatter(1:n,1:n,data);
```

It gives me the error:

```
Error using scatter (line 77)
C must be a single color, a vector the same length as X, or an M-by-3 matrix.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have the image processing toolbox? will `imshow(data)` work by any chance? you can also change the colormap if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are telling matlab to plot only n points ((1,1), (2,2), ..., (n,n)) where you want actually the cartesian product (1:nX1:n). 
Try

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n);

scatter(X(:), Y(:), 10, data(:));

Comment: haha you're right, that's embarassing! now that that's working, any idea on how to change the colors it's using? one is dark red and one is dark blue or something and it's hard to tell them apart

Comment: c=[1 0 0; 0 0 1];
colormap(c);  you can change c around to get your desired colors

Answer (score 1):

`scatter` allows you to plot points with different options (color, size, etc) for ***each*** point depending on a 'Z' value, but it creates a lot of graphic objects (one for each point).

In your case, you only have 2 *subsets* of data (among all your points). The points with value `1` and with value `0`. So another option is to extract these 2 subsets then plot each subset with each a set of common properties.

```
%% // prepare test data
n = 10 ;
data=randi([0 1],n); %// create a 10x10 matrix filled with `0` and `1`

%% // extract the 2 subsets
[x0 , y0] = find( data == 0 ) ;
[x1 , y1] = find( data == 1 ) ;

%% // display
figure ; axes('Nextplot','add')

plotOptions = {'LineStyle','none','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerSize',10} ; %// common options for both plots 

plot(x0,y0,'o','MarkerFaceColor','r', plotOptions{:} ) %// circle marker, red fill
plot(x1,y1,'d','MarkerFaceColor','g', plotOptions{:} ) %// diamond marker, green fill
```

This way you have full control on each subset property (*you can control the size, color, shape etc...*). And you only have 2 graphic objects to handle (instead of n^2).
[image: dots]